# How to get the most recent dated file (filename of the form YYYY-MM-DD-filename.txt) in a directory

Tags: python

Inside a directory `dir2search`, I have many files of the form

```
YYYY-MM-DD-orders.txt
```

where YYYY is the 4 digit year, MM is the 2 digit month (01 for January, 02 for February, etc..) and DD is the 2 digit day of the month (01 for the first, 02 for the second, etc..).

How can I use python to get the most recently dated file?

Currently, I use

```
  def all_orders_files(dir2search) :
    return glob(os.path.join(dir2search, '????-??-??-orders.txt'))

  def most_recent_date() :
    # str2date is a custom function I have that converts date to datetime format
    return max(str2date(os.path.basename(filename)[:10])
                  for filename in all_orders_files())
```

I don't know how efficient this is, but I also don't know of another way to do it. I would like to profile against some other methods.

Comment: As a side note, you might want to consider using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead of the old `os.path` utilities.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way :

```
dir2search = "/home/dir2search/"

files = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir2search, "*-orders.txt"))
print(max(files))
```

Comment: I made an edit in my OP, and I think sorting isn't necessary? we can just use the max function right? this should be faster in theory

Comment: @24n8 true , max() should be faster as long as file names follow the `YYYY-MM-DD`  template. however you still don't need a loop . see updated asnwer

Comment: IIUC, the only difference between your idea and mine is instead of searching for `'????-??-??-orders.txt'`, you use `"*-orders.txt"`?

Comment: That part is actually won't affect the performance that much. Both way works,  in your code you are looping through the list of files and converting it to the date time, that part is unnecessary and max() still works perfectly with dates as string

Answer (score 0):

can you try the following:

```
sorted(self.all_orders_files())[-1]
```

`YYYY-MM-DD` can help in sorting, provided the month and date are `zero-padded decimal number`

Comment: `self.` was a typo. I removed it. 
isn't `sorted(self.all_orders_files())[-1]` what I previously had before I edited it to use the max function?

Comment: I didnt check your edits